# Integrating html templates in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I am using Kentico portal to make an E-commerce site.If I wish to change the design of available sample E-commerce site.Would it be a tidious task ?

Example : If I download e-commerce design templates (i.e html and css files) and I wish to change design of each page of sample kentico site (home page,product detail page etc.)then, what is the most suitable and quick way to achieve this ?

How should I update the html/css of each page of available site with downloaded templates? OR Should I create entirely a new e-commerce site in the portal ?

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box sites are meant to be used as examples and references not to build a production site off of.  The markup used on the Ecommerce site will also be different, considerably different than your purchased template.  I've found it much easier and faster to start from scratch with a blank site and implement all of the design that way.  Make sure you take advantage of shared layouts and templates, this will help make development and re-skins in the future easier.

Comment: Agreed, however note that in Kentico 10, the blank site does not contain many of the Ecommerce templates, so you will want to set up both Blank and an Ecommerce site so you can export the Ecommerce page templates such as the checkout templates, account templates, etc.  Just makes things easier!

Comment: Correct, I'd never setup a template site on the same instance of what will be a production site.  You can export those templates out of a different instance and import them if needed.  OR just have the two instances and copy the webparts as needed.  Do not have both a blank site and the e-commerce templates installed in the same instance it will only cause problems later, especially if you plan to never use the e-commerce site for anything other than a reference.